# Calculating the p(x) of a uniform distribution wrong?

Tags: probability

So say you want to figure out the probability of rolling an 8 in a dice labelled from 6 to 10(inclusive). The equation tells you p(8) = 1/(10-6) = 1/4. This online calculator also confirms it.

[online calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsWs6.png)

How does this make any sense. Aren't there 5 possibilities in a dice from 6-10 as you can roll 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10. Also if you add all the p(x) it equals 1.25 but it should equal 1. Shouldn't the p(8)= 0.2 that way they all add up to 1

Comment: The link you provide appears to describe a (continuous) uniform distribution on the interval $[6,10]$.  Of course that distribution has density $\frac 1{10-6}=\frac 14$.  That is not the probability of getting the value $8$ though...as the distribution is continuous, that probability is $0$.

Comment: Dice rolls are discrete. The formula you used is for a continuous random variable.

Comment: thank you it helped

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$ then $\mathbb P(X=8) = \frac15$.